# free hand painting not work properly?

Tags: android, android-widget

I have used an image which we can select from gallery or maybe use camera. I am using a custom view for zooming and free hand painting on it. I have used canvas and paint for edit on image it works but my issue is that when we start painting on touch event it's drawn but not same x,y coordinate it display below a lot to touch point. Please help me how to improve my code to achieve my goal my code is here...

```
public class EditImage extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{ 
TouchImageView edit_img;//custom image view
Bitmap bitmap;    
String imagepath;
Bitmap alteredBitmap,alteredBitmap1;
Canvas canvas;
Paint paint;
Matrix matrix;
float downx = 0;
float downy = 0;
float upx = 0;
float upy = 0;
int count=0;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */   
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.editscreen2);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Button back_btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.back_button);
    back_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {  
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();
        }
    });

    Intent extras=getIntent();      
    Uri imageFileUri = Uri.parse(extras.getStringExtra("imagepath"));
    edit_img=(TouchImageView)findViewById(R.id.editimage);
    Log.i("imagepath2",imageFileUri+"");
    try {
        BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
               bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream
                         (imageFileUri), null, bmpFactoryOptions);

        alteredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap
                .getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);

        canvas = new Canvas(alteredBitmap);
        paint = new Paint();  
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setDither(true);

        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

            paint.setStrokeWidth(5);     
        matrix = new Matrix();
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, paint);
        Drawable drawable = (Drawable)new BitmapDrawable(alteredBitmap);
        edit_img.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);

    } catch (Exception e) {   
        Log.v("ERROR", e.toString());
    }
    edit_img.setOnTouchListener(this);  
    setfunction();
}
private void setfunction()
{

    Button done_btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.done);
    done_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    done_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {       
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            //  File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_image);
            String imagename = "Image.png";
            File file = new File (root, imagename);
            if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            alteredBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
                out.flush();    
                out.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Intent intent=new Intent(EditImage2.this,SaveImage.class);
            intent.putExtra("imagepath",alteredBitmap);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }); 

    Button erase_btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.erase);
    erase_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            canvas.drawColor(0, Mode.CLEAR);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap,matrix, paint);
        }
    });
}
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if(event.getPointerCount()>1)   
    {
        edit_img.setMaxZoom(4f); 
    }
    else
    {
        int action = event.getAction();     
        switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            downx = event.getX();      
            downy = event.getY();
            Log.i("touch points x,y",downx+"/"+downy);
            break;       
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            upx = event.getX();
            upy = event.getY(); 
            Log.i("touch points upx,upy",upx+"/"+upy);
            canvas.drawLine(downx, downy, upx, upy, paint);
            downx = upx;
            downy = upy;
            Log.i("touch points x,y",downx+"/"+downy);
            //edit_img.invalidate();
            v.invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            upx = event.getX();  
            upy = event.getY();  
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:          
            break;   
        default:   
            break;
        }
    }
    return true;   
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The coordinates you are using (from `event.getX/Y()`) are not relative to the point you think they are. Check the documentation, and/or put some `System.out.printlns` to verify this.

You may need to work with a manual offset (given by the canvas absolute position), for example.

Sorry I'm not more specific: I've been out of Android for a long time. This started out as a comment, but got a little long.

Comment: a lot of thanks for reply but i am not getting how to get canvas absolute position can you ellaborate this point please i am new in android..